# Web App application logs: Failed to load settings from cloud storage?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When enabling application logging (using the built-in Diagnostic Logs) in our Azure Web App, the following messages are logged every minute or less:

> **INFORMATION** There was an exception loading settings from storage. The remote name could not be resolved: 'spmywebapp.blob.core.windows.net'
>   **INFORMATION** There was a problem loading the settings. Failed to load settings from cloud storage.
>   **INFORMATION** Unpacking resources...
>   **INFORMATION** Executing Service Profiler Agent version 1.0.41029.1 with arguments:
>   **INFORMATION** Welcome to Service Profiler - to exit the program press 'Ctrl+C'.
>   **INFORMATION** Detected an Azure Web Sites sandbox.
>   **INFORMATION** Initializing agent...
>   **INFORMATION** Loading settings from cloud storage. Settings name: default

The storage account from the first entry is not something we have ever created or configured.

Where is this coming from and is it a concern?

**EDIT:**

I enabled application logging to be persisted to blob storage:

[image: Diagnostic Logs]

And the log entries are found in these (block) blobs:

[image: Blobs]

Comment: Can you clarify what specific action you are taking in the Azure Portal, and where you are seeing this output?

Comment: @DavidEbbo see edit - thanks

Comment: Maybe this logging is coming from App Insights. Do you have that enabled? And is this a classic .net or Core app?

Comment: @DavidEbbo Yes, we do use Applicable Insights. Classic .NET

Comment: My guess is that it's related to that, and it has some bad configuration pointing to a non-existing storage account.

Comment: I found this storage account configured as a Wep App connection string under the name ServiceProfilerStorage - any idea what this might be?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, and there are no references to it on the web. So it does not look like a standard setting.